# Spring Cloud components confusion

Tags: spring-batch, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-stream, spring-cloud-dataflow, spring-cloud-task

How do these Spring components relate/differ to/from each other? What does each represent conceptually? Would one use them together or are they competing projects?

- Spring Cloud Data Flow
- Spring Cloud Stream
- Spring Cloud Task
- Spring Cloud Task App Starters
- Spring Batch

From my understanding, *SC Tasks* are just "units of work" to execute, a processing unit in the form of a short-lived/task-based microservice. *SC Data Flow* is orchestration for the tasks. These two I (think I) understand how they relate and what they represent conceptually, but a lot of documentation and examples talk about the other projects in the same context.

I also thought that *SC Task* was a replacement for *Spring Batch* but in some examples they seem to imply that Spring Batches are executed inside SC Tasks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks for your interest in Spring Cloud projects! Find below the high-level introductions for the primary projects involved in Spring Cloud Data Flow (SCDF) ecosystem. The [launch blog](https://blog.pivotal.io/big-data-pivotal/products/data-goes-cloud-native-with-the-new-spring-cloud-data-flow) covers the backstory and among other details.

- [Spring Cloud Stream](http://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-stream/) is a lightweight event-driven microservices framework to quickly build applications that can connect to external systems (*eg: Kafka, Cassandra, MySQL, Hadoop, ..*).
- [Spring Cloud Task](http://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-task/) is a short-lived microservices framework to quickly build applications that perform finite amounts of data processing (*eg: batch-jobs, ..*). The connection with Spring Batch framework is explained in the launch blog linked above.
- [Spring Cloud Data Flow](http://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-dataflow/) provides the orchestration mechanics to deploy applications built with Spring Cloud Stream and Spring Cloud Task programming model to a variety of runtime platforms including Cloud Foundry, Apache Yarn, Apache Mesos and Kubernetes. There's community developed SCDF implementations for OpenShift and Nomad, too. More details [here](http://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-dataflow/#spring-cloud-data-flow-implementations).

The [building blocks](http://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-dataflow/#building-blocks-of-spring-cloud-data-flow) visual from the project site should cover the high-level interaction between the various projects in SCDF's ecosystem.

Comment: Thank you @Sabby, the launch blog was very useful. I am still confused wrt Spring Cloud Task App Starters. Is it just a "control API" used by Data Flow to spawn SC Tasks?

Comment: The "Spring Cloud Task App Starters" project provides OOTB ready to use Task/Batch applications such as `sqoop-job`, `spark-job`, `jdbchdfs` etc. We also provide [bulk import links](http://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-task-app-starters/#task-app-starters-and-spring-cloud-data-flow-) to use the already built artifacts in [SCDF directly](http://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-dataflow/docs/current-SNAPSHOT/reference/htmlsingle/#_registering_a_task_application).

Comment: Similarly, we also have "Spring Cloud Stream App Starters" project that provides OOTB ready to use [streaming applications](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-stream-app-starters). See the [reference guide](http://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-stream-app-starters/docs/1.0.4.RELEASE/reference/html/) for more details and there's [bulk import links](http://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-stream-app-starters/#stream-app-starters-and-spring-cloud-data-flow-) to register them in SCDF, too.